# Display text through p5.js

Tags: javascript, string, p5.js

I'm having trouble displaying text in p5.js. I am loading data from a csv file.

```
      let qut = tweetsTable.getRow(row).get("Quote");
      let first = qut.substring(0,44);
```

When I run the following it produces text on the screen:

```
      text(qut, 1100, 0);
```

However, when I try to display the substring it doesn't work:

```
      text(first, 1100, 0);
```

I've checked both `qut` and `first` with the `typeof` function and both are strings. Why is there a difference when trying to display the shorter string compared to the longer one?

Edited to include this minimal reproducible example:

```
let qut = "We are gathered here today to celebrate the life of Edward Snowden, deceased at the ripe young age of 73. He was a brave, bold and wise man";
let first = qut.substring(0,44);

function draw() {
text(qut,500,300);
text(first,750,500);
}
```

Can anyone explain why qut is displayed but first is not?

Comment: Hard to guess with only this little code. Could you please post or link a runnable example? If youwant you can use: editor.p5js.org to cook one :) Any way, if you log `first` to console is it what you expected? I think it should work as expected.

Comment: We need a [mcve] to be able to say. Too much here is left to the imagination. Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully this minimal reproducible example is what you are looking for. Both first and qut log to the console as expected :/

Answer (score 0):

text (p5.js) takes three arguments, the last two arguments have to be inside canvas so text be displayed
So if canvas is 600px wide and 600px height you should display text inside, so
x, y less than 600px

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).